# React - Component is rendered unnecessarily when state is changed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have developed a Clock component using React Function Components. Since I need to refresh the clock for every second. I have used **setTimeout**.

I have stored the *setTimeout Id* as state variable using '**useState**' which is used later to clear the timer when component is unmounted.
I have used state here instead of normal variable since the later will be initialized each and everytime when the component renders and doesn't sustain the last assigned value.

But to my dismay, each time when the timeElement is updated, the component is rendered twice and  I later found out that the component is rendered once again  when the *setTimeout Id* is updated in the local state.

Could you please tell me how to avoid rerendering?

Working demo is available [here](https://codepen.io/rakshu/pen/OJMeQZx?editors=0010)

Edit:
Many have provided solution by using **setInterval** instead of **setTimeout**. This is good but still is it not possible to achieve it using setTimeout itself? Is it like we must move with this solution?

```js
function ClockContainer() {
  let [color, setColor] = React.useState(null);
  let [show, setShow] = React.useState(true);
  let displayBtnClickHandler = function () {
    setShow(!show);
  };
  let onInputChangeHandler = function (orgEvent) {
    setColor(orgEvent.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={displayBtnClickHandler}>
        {show ? "Hide" : "Show"}{" "}
      </button>
      {
       show && <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Color"
          onChange={onInputChangeHandler}
        /> 
      }
      
      {show ? <Clock color={color} /> : <h3>Clock Hidden!!</h3>}
      </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Clock(props) {
  let getTimer = function () {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    let hours = currentTime.getHours();
    return {
      currentTime,
      hours,
      minutes: currentTime.getMinutes(),
      seconds: currentTime.getSeconds(),
      ampm: hours >= 12 ? "pm" : "am"
    };
  };
  let [timeElement, setTimeElements] = React.useState(getTimer());
  let [updateTimer, setUpdateTimer] = React.useState(false);

  let setTimer = function () {
    clearTimeout(updateTimer);
    let updateTimerlocal = setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeElements(getTimer());
    }, 1000);
    setUpdateTimer(updateTimerlocal);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Rendered");
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimer();
  }, [timeElement]);
  /* To call cleanup codes when destroyed useEffect with empty array needs to be passed */
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return function () {
      console.log("UnMounted!!");
      clearTimeout(setTimer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
      <div className="clock" style={{ backgroundColor: props.color }}>
        {timeElement.hours === 0
          ? 12
          : timeElement.hours > 12
          ? timeElement.hours - 12
          : timeElement.hours}
        :
        {timeElement.minutes > 9
          ? timeElement.minutes
          : `0${timeElement.minutes}`}
        :
        {timeElement.seconds > 9
          ? timeElement.seconds
          : `0${timeElement.seconds}`}{" "}
        {timeElement.ampm}
      </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ClockContainer />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
:root {
  --firstColor: rgba(0, 169, 158, 1);
  --secondColor: rgba(0, 191, 150, 1);
  --textColor: #fff;
}

.clock {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 29px;
  color: var(--textColor);
  line-height: 2em;
  background: var(--firstColor);
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .clock {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 699px) {
  .clock {
    font-size: 45px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 499px) {
  .clock {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id=app></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React component re-renders for every state change. If you want to persist a value in the component without having to re-render it for value change, you can use useRef. Always have the dependant function (setTimer) within useEffect. That is the recommended solution by React. I have provided the solution in the [link](https://codepen.io/aishwarya257/pen/zYrVJWW?editors=0011).

```
  const timerRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const setTimer = function () {
      clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
      timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        setTimeElements(getTimer());
      }, 1000);
    };
    setTimer();
    return function () {
      // console.log("UnMounted!!");
      clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
    };
  }, [timeElement]);
```

Comment: Thank you @Aishwarya for the solution. I got to know about "useRef". But in this usecase we can have it as local variable instead of "useRef". Yours and Soapnrope's solution combined, I could arrive at this solution - https://codepen.io/rakshu/pen/rNxEERM?editors=0011. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are making re-render loop by updating `timeElement` via useEffect loop that calls `setTimer()`.

To fix that, just call `setTimer()` once:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   setTimer();
}, []);
```

and swap setTimeout to setInterval. Please note - recheck if clearTimeouts are now called correctly and no memory leak is introduced.

[See updated example](https://codepen.io/soapnrope/pen/VweJXXy?editors=0010)

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Soapnrope. But even in this case, for the first time, the component is rendered twice. Could you find solution to avoid it?

Comment: @rachCoder27 I updated the example again [codepen](https://codepen.io/soapnrope/pen/VweJXXy?editors=0010). Essentially I removed setTimer and made it a simple useEffect that will handle the `clearTimeout`. I also removed `getTimer` to function outside the component other wise if you define functions inside component scope they will be reassigned on every render. In this case its not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is 2 useStates `setTimeElements` and `setUpdateTimer`. Both are called and each of them is causing the re-render.

`setUpdateTimer` seems unnecessary here as it has no relation with UI update. It can be plain javascript variable to store id.

Here is the fixed bit. The variable `updateTimerlocal` has been moved out. Before assigning a new value, am clearing the interval to avoid multiple intervals.

```
  let [timeElement, setTimeElements] = React.useState(getTimer());
  let updateTimerlocal = null;
  let setTimer = function () {
    if (updateTimerlocal) clearTimeout(updateTimer);
    updateTimerlocal = setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeElements(getTimer());
    }, 1000);
  };
```

Additionally, [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) will be a better choice instead of setTimeout for this timer use case.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/clarifications.

Comment: I tried your solution, when the component is unmounted, still the timer is not cleared. updateTimerlocal is not getting updated properly. You can check here - https://codepen.io/rakshu/pen/JjGQZOP?editors=0010. Even after it is unmounted by clicking on hide button, still the timer runs.

Comment: That's because `updateTimerlocal` has to be cleared(use `clearInterval`) when the component is unmounted. With `setInterval`, we use `clearInterval`. Do `clearInterval` inside the function which you are returning in the useEffect hook(alongside clearTimeout of setTimer) and it should work fine

Comment: Hi, it is updated. But still the issue is the same. Its okay I got it "updateTimerlocal" declaration must be moved inside useEffect hook that is using it. @Sunil

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this function here you have your logic defined and also you are setting your state that is setTimeElements(getTimer());

```
 let setTimer = function () {
    clearTimeout(updateTimer);
    let updateTimerlocal = setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeElements(getTimer());
    }, 1000);
    setUpdateTimer(updateTimerlocal);
  };
```

And you are calling this function inside useFffect and also you have dependency timeElement

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
        setTimer();
    }, [timeElement]);
```

so when your state timeElement changes that makes your useEffect to be called again

so it is better to remove the dependency as  @Soapnrope mentioned so that it will be called once

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimer();
  }, []);
```